# python dict/list comprehension: why is it slower than for loop?

Tags: python

Consider that `events` here has about 48,000 dictionary objects:

```
keyed_events = { gid: [ r for r in events if r['gid'] == gid ] for gid in gidlist }
```

Is about 4x slower than:

```
keyed_events = {}
for event in events:
    gid = event['gid']
    if gid not in keyed_events:
        keyed_events[gid] = []
    keyed_events[gid].append(event)
```

Though the former looks more efficient. Why is it slower? Iterating through `events` each pass of the dict comprehension?

Comment: Could `[ r for r in events if r['gid'] == gid ]` be replaced with `filter`? Not sure if that would be the same slowness

Comment: Yeah: `keyed_events = { gid: filter(lambda x: x['gid'] == gid, events) for gid in gidlist }` gives you the same slow run time

Comment: At least it "looks" *more* efficient :D

Answer (score 4):

```
keyed_events = { gid: [ r for r in events if r['gid'] == gid ] for gid in gidlist }
```

The list/dict comprehension runs for `len(gidlist)*len(events)` number of times as it loops over `events` inside of a loop over `gidlist`.

The for loop, on the other hand, has just a single for loop over `events` with a `gid not in keyed_events` which is a `O(1)` operation

Answer (score 3):

Your dictionary + list comprehension more closely matches this code:

```
keyed_events = {}
for gid in gidlist:
    for r in events:
        if r['gid'] == gid:
            keyed_events[gid].append(r)
```

Notice that the loop is *doubly nested*. You loop over all of the events for each gid.

A closer match to your iterative code would be this:

```
keyed_events = itertools.groupby(events, 'gid')
```

Comment: `itertools.groupby` requires groups to be contiguous, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because in the snippet you're iterating through both `gidlist` and `events` but in the first method but iterating through just `events`.

totally I think the inner inline `for` is inefficient